# Adding dot after chapter number in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, koma-script

I need to add dot in the TOC after the chapter number. It needs to look like this:

**1. Logoc-sarx – Ein in Fleisch gekleideter Gott**

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles]{scrbook}%
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,ngerman]{babel}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{longtable}%
\usepackage{tabularx}%
\usepackage{array}%
\usepackage{float}%
\usepackage{setspace}%
\usepackage{tabto}%
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{nameref}%
\usepackage{xpatch}%
\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{rotating}%
\usepackage[textwidth=2cm, textsize=tiny, backgroundcolor=white, linecolor=black]{todonotes}%
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{newtxtext}% Times font
\usepackage{newtxsf}
\usepackage{textcomp}%
%
% TEXT
\newcommand{\grk}[1]{{\foreignlanguage{polutonikogreek}{#1}}}% GREEK TEXT
\newcommand{\lat}[1]{\emph{{#1}}}% LATIN TEXT
%
%
% BIBLATEX:%
%
\usepackage[style=historische-zeitschrift, maxnames=2, hyperref=false, backref=true, backrefstyle=none, backend=bibtex,idemtracker=true, block=none]{biblatex}% change to hyperref=true to get clickable links
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}%
\bibliography{Inhalt}
%
%
%
% REDESIGNING TITLE STYLES (REQUIRES TITLESEC)
%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]% CHAPTER
  {\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont\scshape\centering}
  {\scshape\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.\enskip}{1pt}{\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont}
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{30pt}% FIRST NUMBER BEFORE LAST NUMBER AFTER
\titleformat{\section}[block]% SECTION
  {\fontsize{10.5}{8}\selectfont\centering}
  {\thesection.\enskip}{1pt}{\fontsize{10.5}{8}\selectfont}
  \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{15pt}{15pt}% FIRST NUMBER BEFORE LAST NUMBER AFTER
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]% SUBSECTION
  {\fontsize{10.5}{8}\selectfont\centering\itshape}
  {\itshape\thesubsection.\enskip}{1pt}{\fontsize{10.5}{8}\selectfont}
  \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{15pt}{10pt}% FIRST NUMBER BEFORE LAST NUMBER AFTER
%
%
\begin{document}%
%
%
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{scrheadings}%
\chapter{\grk{L'ogoc-s'arx} – Ein in Fleisch gekleideter Gott}\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{\grk{<Omoo'usios} – Der gottgleiche Sohn}
    \blindtext
    \begin{quote}\grk{o>uko~un t~w m`en >agenn'htw patr`i o>ike~ion >ax'iwma fulakt'eon, mhd'ena to~u e@inai a>ut~w t`on a>'ition l'egontas; t~w d`e u<i~w t`hn <arm'ozousan tim`hn >aponemht'eon, t`hn >'anarqon a>ut~w par`a to~u patr`os g'ennhsin >anatij'entas; ka`i <ws >efj'asamen a>ut~w s'ebas >apon'emontes, m'onon e>usebos ka`i e>uf'hmws t`o @hn ka`i t`o >ae`i ka`i t`o pr`o a>i'wnwn l'egontes >ep> a>uto~u, t`hn m'entoi je'othta a>uto~u m`h paraito'umenoi, >all`a t~h e>ik'oni ka`i t~w qarakt~hri to~u patr`os >aphkribwm'enhn >emf'ereian kat`a p'anta >anatij'entes, t`o d`e >ag'ennhton t~w patr`i m'onon >id'iwma pare~inai dox'azontes, <'ate d`h ka`i a>uto~u f'askontos to~u swt~hros; »<o pat'hr mou me'izwn mo'u >estin«.}\end{quote}
    \blindtext
    \cleardoublepage
    \end{document}%
```

Comment: This is not a *minimal* working example. Note also: Usage of `titlesec` with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended. However, try `numbers=enddot`.

Comment: Ok I trimmed the MWE now (I left the packages included because sometimes some package causes clashes). `numbers=enddot`worked! Can you post this as reply so that I can accept it as answer? Does this affect any other part of the document or is this only applied on TOC? I wouldn't like having extra dots somewhere else because of this :)

Comment: I'm almost sure, that we already have a question like this. But currently I've not the time to search for it. And a real answer should also replace `titlesec` by `\RedeclareSectionCommand`, `\raggedsection`-change etc. But currently I've not the time to do it.

Comment: Ok thanks for this! I can't remove `titlesec` because I use it for other things too. For not it works for me but I will keep in mind that it needs to be replaced in future if I want to work with Koma-Script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add KOMA-Script option `numbers=enddot` as suggested by @Schweinebacke.

In the following example I have removed package `titlesec` and used KOMA-Script commands instead:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,
  sfdefaults=false,% needs version 3.39 or newer, replaces egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles,
  chapterprefix,% <- added
  numbers=enddot
]{scrbook}%
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,ngerman]{babel}%
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% not needed with an uptodate TeX Distribution
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{titlesec,showframe}

\usepackage{newtxtext}% Times font
\usepackage{newtxsf}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand{\grk}[1]{{\foreignlanguage{polutonikogreek}{#1}}}% GREEK TEXT
\newcommand{\lat}[1]{\emph{{#1}}}% LATIN TEXT


\renewcommand\raggedsection{\centering}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-30pt,
  afterskip=30pt,
  innerskip=1pt,
  font=\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont\mdseries\scshape
]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-15pt,
  afterskip=15pt,
  font=\fontsize{10.5}{11}\selectfont\mdseries
]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-15pt,
  afterskip=10pt,
  font=\fontsize{10.5}{11}\selectfont\mdseries\itshape
]{section}

\begin{document}%

\tableofcontents

\chapter{\grk{L'ogoc-s'arx} – Ein in Fleisch gekleideter Gott}\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{\grk{<Omoo'usios} – Der gottgleiche Sohn}
\blindtext
\begin{quote}\grk{o>uko~un t~w m`en >agenn'htw patr`i o>ike~ion >ax'iwma fulakt'eon, mhd'ena to~u e@inai a>ut~w t`on a>'ition l'egontas; t~w d`e u<i~w t`hn <arm'ozousan tim`hn >aponemht'eon, t`hn >'anarqon a>ut~w par`a to~u patr`os g'ennhsin >anatij'entas; ka`i <ws >efj'asamen a>ut~w s'ebas >apon'emontes, m'onon e>usebos ka`i e>uf'hmws t`o @hn ka`i t`o >ae`i ka`i t`o pr`o a>i'wnwn l'egontes >ep> a>uto~u, t`hn m'entoi je'othta a>uto~u m`h paraito'umenoi, >all`a t~h e>ik'oni ka`i t~w qarakt~hri to~u patr`os >aphkribwm'enhn >emf'ereian kat`a p'anta >anatij'entes, t`o d`e >ag'ennhton t~w patr`i m'onon >id'iwma pare~inai dox'azontes, <'ate d`h ka`i a>uto~u f'askontos to~u swt~hros; »<o pat'hr mou me'izwn mo'u >estin«.}\end{quote}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```